# Flex - populate Combobox with arrayCollection with data from javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript, photoshop-script

I am developing a panel in Photoshop with Flex and Extendscript. I am pretty close to getting this to work, but with my Flex skills I am having a little issue with the Array I am pulling in from the jsx file. The array is displayed fine in the alert box, but somewhere between my split and creating new collection something is wrong. Thanks for any  help on this.

Here is my Flex

```
protected function loadData():void {
    var grabFolderNames:SyncRequestResult = CSXSInterface.instance.evalScript("labNames");
    var list:String = grabFolderNames.data;
    var array:Array = list.split(",");
    var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    arrayCollection.source = array;
    labFolderList.dataProvider = arrayCollection;
}
```

and here is the jsx

```
function labNames() {
  var labs = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow"];
    alert("This function is firing" + labs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should modify your labNames() method to return the array:

```
function labNames() {
    var labs = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow"];
    return labs;
}
```

2) Make sure in the HTML Wrapper for your flex object you have `allowScriptAccess="always"` (or `allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"`) in order to enable javascript/Flex communication.

3) If it still doesn't work, replace

```
var grabFolderNames:SyncRequestResult = CSXSInterface.instance.evalScript("labNames");
```

by:

```
var obj:* = CSXSInterface.instance.evalScript("labNames");
```

then put a breakpoint on that line and see if "obj" is populated by some data and report results here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does, thanks man. All ArrayCollections have to be dealt with as objects. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the CSXSInterface but, since `labNames()` just displays the string in an alert, and does not return it as a String, `grabFolderNames.data` may not contain what you expect it to contain. Why don't you check its value with a debugger?